# Need to pause bash script for user examination

Tags: bash, redirect

I have a bash script that should run as follows:  Read a line from a (large) file, process the line, display the results, wait for a run signal from the user, start over.  Right now it looks like

```
while read newline
do
# process newline
# display newline
read go_ahead
done < my_input_file.txt
```

The processing and displaying look sort of OK, but it's hard to tell because -- here's my problem -- the script won't stop to read the go_ahead variable.  I am guessing this is because it thinks it's supposed to read newline *and* go_ahead from my_input_file.txt?  In any event, can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: Any reason you can't simply pipe the output of the loop to a pager like `less` instead of making the user respond to *every* line?

Comment: Actually, that's a thought.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this might be to use a separate file descriptor for your input data. Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exec 3< /path/to/inputfile.txt

while read -u 3 newline; do
  processed=$(tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]' <<<"$newline")
  printf '%s\n' "$processed"
  read go_ahead
done
```

Comment: I'd just redirect fd 3 to the loop itself (`while; ...; do 3< /path/to/inputfile.txt`) rather than do so globally.

Comment: @chepner  Not familiar with this.  Would appreciate if you could elaborate.  Thanks.

Comment: `exec` sets file descriptor 3 for the entire shell, so it is still open (although pointing at the end of the file) after the loop completes. Redirecting the file to the `while` compound command opens the file only when the loop starts, and closes the file once the loop completes.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3>&1

while read line; do
        echo $line
        read -u 3 -p 'continue(y/n)? ' yn
        [[ $yn == n ]] && break
done < "$1"

exit 0
```

The `-u` arg to read let's you specify another descriptor.